# Is it possible to make a single-faced cylinder in Blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh

In unreal engine 4 they give us some basic static mesh to work with and well the cylinder has only one face so that when i apply a material to it it renders well. Now here is my problem.

I am trying to make a prison door with metal bars in it. When i make a cylinder in blender it renders with so many faces. When i bring to ue4 I cant apply any materials to it because it really doesn't come out good. Any thoughts on how to fix that would so much appreciated!

thank you.

Comment: Could you post a picture of the "single-face-cylinder"? Is the cylinder you are looking for maybe as single plane that use a normal map to to fake its roundness, or its a freshly implemented kind of "true" geometry that UE4 is able to achieve? Anyway, more info about your target object will be appreciated

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "single faced sphere", could you please post a screenshot of what you are talking about?

Comment: I think he is looking for smooth cylinder

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Cylinders have as many faces as you accept when you create them.  Reduce the number of faces when you create a cylinder.  Have the information panels open when you create the cylinder so you can see the information. Press <kbd>T</kbd> to show and hide the panel.

You can render a 3D view as a png with a transparent background.  So you could apply the texture to a single plane with little geometry if that suits your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UV map of your cylinder or change your texture mapping. When given absolutely no texture coords, Blender will just map your texture to each face or tri.

What you need to do: tell Blender you don't want it to do that.

UVMaps are their own tutorial, and there is much info available.

If you don't want to create a UVMap, (weird) you can change the texture mapping settings in Blender.

Using a 'Tube' projection is probably what you are looking for. Then, your texture is projected around the entire surface of the tube/cylinder as '1 face'.

[image: mapping settings]